# Heroku Database available from anywhere

Tags: database, heroku

I'm running a python app on heroku with a postgres database.

If I enter the credentials in PGAdmin or add it to a django installation on my *local* environment, I'm able to start write and read operations.

While this is supercomfortable to debug, it feels kind of insecure.

Sure, it's ssl, but is this a normal usecase?

If not, how would I change that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you should consider it the normal use case but to be on the safe side you should "fork" the database and work on this new copy. More here: https://postgres.heroku.com/fork

Comment: I'm not afraid of accedentially writing something wrong, I'm afraid of having the database credentials available for anyone who gains access to my computer (or computer of my colleagues). It essentially means: Steal one computer, steal the entire business data.

Comment: @shredding Then don't store the credentials on your computer. Another possibility is to encrypt your hard drive.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem! I would enter and delete userid and password every time I would need to do something and store it in a password safe like 1Password.